# memcached install issues with lib event on server

Tags: php, linux, memcached, installation

I've installed libevent on my server in the directory root/data/ and have i'm about to install memcached with

```
./configure –with-lib-event=/data/; make; make install
```

However, after running a bit I get this error saying i'm pointing to the wrong directory for libevent.

```
checking for libevent directory... configure: error: libevent is required.  You can get it from http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/

      If it's already installed, specify its path using --with-libevent=/dir/

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Any suggestions. I am not experience with cli so anything is help.  Thanks!

Comment: Libevent probably is not in /data/. You could try to run configure without the flag and it will often look in default locations. If that doesnt work, then supply a path, but make sure its the path to the libevent header files.

Comment: Why not install memcached using your server's package manager?
This will save you a lot of time and effort. People more intimately involved with compiling software have already done most of the work for you.

Comment: "root/data/" is a relative path - do you mean "/root/data/"? "/data/" ? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
find /lib /usr/lib /usr/local/lib | grep -i libevent.so
```

Then use directory it finds libevent.so as configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To actually install `memcached` & `libevent` from source, which I don't recommend unless you're building Linux from Scratch or developing those applications (obviously that is not your case):

1. Become root with something like `sudo su`
2. Navigate to your home folder `cd ~/`
3. Download libevent sources `wget https://github.com/libevent/libevent/archive/release-2.1.6-beta.tar.gz`
4. Unpack them & go to the resulting dir `tar xzvf release-2.1.6-beta.tar.gz && cd libevent-release-2.1.6-beta`
5. Run the following commands to prepare sources: `libtoolize`, then `autoreconf`, then `automake --add-missing` and finally `autoreconf` again.
6. Configure them with the following command: `./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules --disable-samples --disable-debug-mode --disable-malloc-replacement --enable-openssl --disable-static --disable-libevent-regress --enable-thread-support`
7. Finally `make && make install`
8. Go back to your home dir `cd ~/`
9. Download memcached sources: `wget https://memcached.org/files/memcached-1.4.31.tar.gz`
10. Unpack them & navigate to their directory `tar xzvf memcached-1.4.31.tar.gz && cd memcached-1.4.31`
11. Configure with the following command: `./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules --disable-docs --disable-sasl`
12. `make && make install`

That will get you memacached. Though again you really should consider stopping whatever your are trying to do & install memcached from your system repository. Try this commands with & without adding `sudo` before them: `yum install memcached`, `apt-get install memcached`, `yast2 -i memcached`